# Задать высоту первому ряду сетки grid

Tags: html, css, grid

Подскажите, как задать высоту первому ряду сетки на гридах? Необходимо, чтобы высота в первом ряду была больше, чем у остальных дивов.
https://codepen.io/drsg/pen/OJpmKgW

```
<div id="container">
 <div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<styles>
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(11, minmax(50px, 80px));
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #555;
}
</styles>
```

Comment: Сталкивался с похожей ситуацией. Мне помогла вот эта [статья](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).
Если не получится напишите тут, я пропишу.

Comment: grid-template-rows: 100px repeat(10, minmax(50px, 80px));